# Find all link before specific selector Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="inpost">
    <a href="">Link1</a>
    <div class="">
        <a href="">Link2</a>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">Link3 </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="">Link4</a>
    <a href="">Link5</a>
    <a href="">Link6</a>
    <a href="">Link7</a> [Size = M, L]
    <a href="">Link8</a>

    <a name="more"></a> something

    <br>
    <a href=""></a> something
    <br> something
    <br>something
    <br>
</div>
```

I use jQuery to find all `a` tags before `<a name="more"></a>` but it not working.

```
$("[name='more']").prevAll().find('a').each(function(){
  ...
});
```

Can you please suggest me how to do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try extracting the `prevAll` collection into a variable, then `filter` that collection for `a`s (to get matching siblings), and then `add` additional `a`s with `.find` (to get matching descendants):

```js
const prev = $("[name='more']").prevAll();
prev.filter('a').add(prev.find('a')).each(function(){
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inpost">
<a href="">Link1</a>
<div class="">
  <a href="">Link2</a>
  <div class="">
    <a href="">Link3 </a>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="">Link4</a>
<a href="">Link5</a>
<a href="">Link6</a>
<a href="">Link7</a>
[Size = M, L]
<a href="">Link8</a>

<a name="more"></a>

something<br>
<a href="">link9, do not match</a>
something<br>
something<br>something<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is so awesome !!

Answer (score 2):

`find` selects only the children nodes.

One way to do what you want is to loop through all the previous nodes, which you got using `prevAll()`, and check if it is an `a` or something else.

If it is not an `a`, then use `find` to select all the children `a`s.

```js
$("[name='more']").prevAll('*').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is('a')) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  } else {
    $(this).find('a').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inpost">
  <a href="">Link1</a>
  <div class="">
    <a href="">Link2</a>
    <div class="">
      <a href="">Link3 </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="">Link4</a>
  <a href="">Link5</a>
  <a href="">Link6</a>
  <a href="">Link7</a> [Size = M, L]
  <a href="">Link8</a>

  <a name="more">more</a> something

  <br>
  <a href=""></a>
  something<br> something
  <br>something<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and easy

```
$("a[name='more']").prevAll('a').each(function() {
  // here your logic
})
```

Comment: Did you really test it?

Comment: Does it select the `a`s inside the `div`s?

Comment: It selects all siblings `a` s before `<a name="more">`

Answer (score 0):

**You can Also try this code**

```js
var flag =0;
jQuery(document).find('a').each(function(index, el) {
 if (!flag) {
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'more') {
   flag =1;
   return false;
  }else {
   $(this).addClass('myclass');
   
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.myclass {
    background: red
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="inpost">
 <a href="">Link1</a>
 <div class="">
   <a href="">Link2</a>
   <div class="">
     <a href="">Link3 </a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <a href="">Link4</a>
 <a href="">Link5</a>
 <a href="">Link6</a>
 <a href="">Link7</a>
 [Size = M, L]
 <a href="">Link8</a>

 <a name="more">link more</a>

 something<br>
 <a href="">last not styled</a>
 something<br>
 something<br>something<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need all `a` elements before desired `a` (**even inside other tags**), Try this:

```
$(function(){
    console.log((function(p){return p.filter("a").add(p.find("a"));})($("[name='more']").prevAll()).length);
});
```

---

i posted this answer because my prev post was a answer for this need: "we need all prev `a`s that have same parent". but this answer returns all prev `a`s with every parent.